# Excel fill cell color in adjacent cells

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a grid in excel with numbers in it. for example:

[image: Example Grid]

The grid is much larger than the example and the numbers are arbitrary for the example.

I'd like to compare the numbers in the odd columns, i.e. Col1 and Col3, with their adjacent columns, i.e. Col2 and Col4. I want to see if the values in Col1 cells are more than 2x the adjacent cell value in Col2 and if Col2 values are more than 2x the adjacent values in Col1. The same criteria applies to Col3 and Col4. If the values are out of variance I want to change the color of both cells to light red.

I'd like to apply the same algorithm to all the cells in the grid, or have 2 algorithms, one for the odd number columns, another for the even number columns.

I tried using "Conditional Formatting". Comparing Col1 to Col2 works correctly with
=((B6 * 2) <= C6)
but comparing Col2 to Col1 with
=((C6 * 2) <= B6)
does not produce the expected results. In fact it looks like it's actually comparing Col2 to its right hand neighbor Col3, which is no good.

Questions:
Is there a way using "Conditional Formatting" to compare a right hand cell with its left hand neighbor?

Is there a better approach, maybe using a VBA macro or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

This *can* be done with conditional formatting.

Taken from context, your column labeled "Col 1" is Column B, and your first row of data is row 2

1. Select the data range: B2:E4 in the example
2. Enter a CF rule formula (this will colour Col 1, Col 3 etc)
   `=AND(ISEVEN(COLUMN()),OR(B2>C2*2,C2>B2*2))`
3. Enter another rule (this will colour Col 2, Col 4 etc)
   `=AND(ISODD(COLUMN()),OR(A2>B2*2,B2>A2*2))`

[image]

Notes:

1. The Formulas assume that the data range starts in B2. If yours starts somewhere else, adjust the references accodingly.
2. The Formulas assume your data starts on an Even numbered column.  If it in fact starts on an Odd numbered column, swap the `ISEVEN` and `ISODD` functions
3. I've used two different colours to show the effect of the two rules.  You can of course use the same colour for both
4. I've used two rules as I think this is clearer.  You could combine them into one rule if you want
   `=OR(AND(ISEVEN(COLUMN()),OR(B2>C2*2,C2>B2*2)),AND(ISODD(COLUMN()),OR(A2>B2*2,B2>A2*2)))`

Comment: Thanks, that works exactly as I needed. Thanks also for the other great answers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Suppose the numbers start at row 2)

```
Sub Test()
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For c = 1 To 4 Step 2
            If Cells(r, c).Value * 2 <= Cells(r, c + 1).Value Or Cells(r, c + 1).Value * 2 <= Cells(r, c).Value Then
                Cells(r, c).Resize(1, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 153)
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I put my upper left data point in cell B6, then a conditional formatting formula like this

```
=IF(MOD(COLUMN(),2),OR(B6*2<=A6,A6*2<=B6),OR(B6*2<=C6,C6*2<=B6))
```

over cells B6 onwards seems to do the trick.  The logical test of the `IF` statement checks whether the column is even or odd.  Based on that, it either looks backwards one cell (TRUE case here) or forwards one cell (FALSE case here).  Good luck!